# Not sure how to handle exceptions using try catch if element was not found

Tags: c#, selenium, try-catch, browser-automation

I am trying to handle the error message on login page by clearing the Username field from the entered input.

Here is my code:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using TestProject.Common.Extensions;
using TestProject.SDK;
using TestProject.SDK.Tests;
using TestProject.SDK.Tests.Helpers;

namespace SecondTest
{
    public class LoginTest : IWebTest
    {
        public object Assert { get; private set; }
        public object TimeUnit { get; private set; }
        public object InvalidInputErrorTxt { get; private set; }
        public bool IWebelement { get; private set; }
        public bool ErrorMsg { get; private set; }

        public ExecutionResult Execute(WebTestHelper helper)
        {
            var driver = helper.Driver;
            var URL = "https://www.office1.bg/login";
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            driver.FindElementById("CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonAccept").Click();
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            //Login
            Pages.LoginPage LoginPage = new Pages.LoginPage(driver);
            LoginPage.PerformLogin("atanas.grudev1@gmail.com", "123456789");
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            try
            {
                IWebElement Level = driver.FindElementByClassName("corporal-page-list-item");
                if (Level.Displayed)
                {
                    Level.Click();
                    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
                    driver.FindElementByClassName("corporate-login-button-wrapper").Click();
                    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
                    return ExecutionResult.Passed;
                }
                else
                {
                    IWebElement ErrorMsg = driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='loginForm']/div/div[1]");
                    if (ErrorMsg.Displayed)
                    {
                        LoginPage.TxtUserName.Clear();
                        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
                        return ExecutionResult.Failed;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            return ExecutionResult.Passed;
        }       
            }  
        }
```

Seems ExecutionResult at the beginning requires return ExecutionResult.Passed/Failed; at the end of the code, but since I have try - catch I am not sure how to get the correct result. End goal is:
If valid credentials are entered code from the first if statement should be executed and to get Passed result. 
If the entered credentials are not valid the website will throw an error and if the error is present on the the screen the input from the username field should be cleared and get the Failed Result.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: return `ExecutionResult.Failed;` in the catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few suggestions:

1. In general, you want to avoid use of `try-catch` to control code flow whenever possible. In this case, you can use `driver.FindElements()` (note the plural ElementS) and check for an empty list to avoid exceptions being thrown when no element is found. This is a best practice according to [the docs](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-).

   > findElement should not be used to look for non-present elements, use findElements(By) and assert zero length response instead.
2. Setting the timeout for `ImplicitWait` only needs to be done once. Once set, that timeout is applied automatically every time an element is searched for. It doesn't actually wait when called... I think maybe you are confusing it with `WebDriverWait`?
3. Using `ImplicitWait` is not recommended by the Selenium contributors. You should instead use `WebDriverWait` each time you need to wait.
4. I would suggest you investigate and use the Page Object Model. If done right, it will save you a lot of time with code reuse, make your project much more organized, and make your test code a lot cleaner. It looks like you are trying to use something like Page Objects with your `LoginPage.PerformLogin()` call but all your `driver.FindElement()` calls should be in the appropriate page object and you should have one page object per "page".

Here's the code after implementing the first two suggestions. I'll let you do #3 and #4, if you choose to. I removed the `try-catch`, added new `if`s, and removed all but the first `ImplicitWait` set.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using TestProject.Common.Extensions;
using TestProject.SDK;
using TestProject.SDK.Tests;
using TestProject.SDK.Tests.Helpers;

namespace SecondTest
{
    public class LoginTest : IWebTest
    {
        public object Assert { get; private set; }
        public object TimeUnit { get; private set; }
        public object InvalidInputErrorTxt { get; private set; }
        public bool IWebelement { get; private set; }
        public bool ErrorMsg { get; private set; }

        public ExecutionResult Execute(WebTestHelper helper)
        {
            var driver = helper.Driver;
            var URL = "https://www.office1.bg/login";
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            driver.FindElementById("CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonAccept").Click();

            //Login
            Pages.LoginPage LoginPage = new Pages.LoginPage(driver);
            LoginPage.PerformLogin("atanas.grudev1@gmail.com", "123456789");

            IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> level = driver.FindElementsByClassName("corporal-page-list-item");
            if (level.Any() && level.ElementAt(0).Displayed)
            {
                level.ElementAt(0).Click();
                driver.FindElementByClassName("corporate-login-button-wrapper").Click();

                return ExecutionResult.Passed;
            }

            IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> errorMsg = driver.FindElementsByXPath("//*[@id='loginForm']/div/div[1]");
            if (errorMsg.Any() && errorMsg.ElementAt(0).Displayed)
            {
                LoginPage.TxtUserName.Clear();
                return ExecutionResult.Failed;
            }

            return ExecutionResult.Passed;
        }
    }
}
```

A few notes on the new code that you may not have seen before.

1. `.Any()` is an equivalent in LINQ to `.Count > 0`. It returns `true` if the list is not empty, and `false` otherwise.
2. `.ElementAt()` is a LINQ method that allows you to access a member of the collection by index. NOTE: Even though it has "Element" in the name, it has nothing to do with `WebElement` or Selenium.

Let me know if you have any questions.